# Geodesic deviation equation with lowered indices

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

I am studying General Relativity from Schutz's book. In chapter 7 he starts with the geodesics equation with lowered indices:
$$ p^{\alpha}p_{\beta;\alpha} = 0 \qquad(7.25) $$

and goes on to derive the equation :
$$ m\frac{dp_\beta}{dt} = \frac12 g_{\nu\alpha,\beta} p^\nu p^\alpha \qquad(7.29)$$

I understand his derivation but i do not understand how we get equation 7.25 from the geodesics equation: $$ \nabla_p p =0 \qquad (7.10)$$  can someone help please?

Comment: They are pretty much the same by definition.

Comment: You are referring to the *geodesic equation* and not to the *geodesic deviation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CameronGibson is right: $\nabla_p:=p^\alpha\nabla_\alpha$, so $\nabla_p q_\beta=p^\alpha\nabla_\alpha q_\beta=p^\alpha q_{\beta;\,\alpha}$.

Comment: Thank you. I think i had misunderstood the nabla notation.